May Jews play Chinese checkers on Shabbat
According to Halacha, May Jews play Chinese checkers on Shabbat or no? Does it violate any issur like muktzeh or something else?

Do you mean this game specifically about which one would think the rules for games in general don't apply?

Related: "Chess on Shabbat?" Could you elaborate in the question, how you think Chinese checkers would differ from chess, regarding Shabbat? (Chess being a more common/recognizable board game [in the West].)
